# ind the time in which the 15th tap alone can fill the empty cistern given the following conditions?.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> There are t taps numbered 1,2 and so on till t, each of which can fill a cistern. the rate of filling of the nth ta is such that it is equal to twice that of all the taps from 1 to (n-1) put together. If the 18th tap can fill the cistern in 2 minutes, then find the time in which the 15th tap alone can fill the empty cistern.

options:
a) $27$
b) $34$
c) $54$
d) $72$

My Approach:

Let 1st tap can fill the cistern in T mins.

2nd tap: T/2 mins

3rd tap: half the time taken by 1st and 2nd tap combined. : T/$2$ +T/$4$=3T/$4$

And we have,

18th tap: 2 mins

> Am i going right in my approach.Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You have many questions on taps filling up tanks! Where do you get them from?

Comment: @hypergeometric From Internet I pick random and some My friends gave which I was not able to solve with them while in group discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let
$r_i$ be the flow rate of the $i$-th tap
$t_i$ be the time taken for the $i$-th tap alone to fill the cistern.

$$r_n=2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}r_i\\
r_n-r_{n-1}=2\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}r_i-2\sum_{i=1}^{n-2}r_i=2r_{n-1}\\
r_n=3r_{n-1}$$

Volume of tank is given by 
$$r_{18}\cdot t_{18}=r_{15}\cdot t_{15}\\
t_{15}=\frac{r_{18}}{r_{15}}\cdot t_{18}=\frac {3^3r_{15}}{r_{15}}\cdot 2=54\;\text{mins}\qquad\blacksquare$$